# What is the most efficient way of checking N-way equation equivalence in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

Suppose I have a set of Z3 expressions:

```py
exprs = [A, B, C, D, E, F]
```

I want to check whether any of them are equivalent and, if so, determine which. The most obvious way is just an N×N comparison (assume `exprs` is composed of some arbitrarily-complicated boolean expressions instead of the simple numbers in the example):

```py
from z3 import *
exprs = [IntVal(1), IntVal(2), IntVal(3), IntVal(4), IntVal(3)]
for i in range(len(exprs) - 1):
  for j in range(i+1, len(exprs)):
    s = Solver()
    s.add(exprs[i] != exprs[j])
    if unsat == s.check():
      quit(f'{(i, j)} are equivalent')
```

Is this the most efficient method, or is there some way of quantifying over a set of arbitrary expressions? It would also be acceptable for this to be a two-step process where I first learn whether *any* of the expressions are equivalent, and then do a longer check to see which specific expressions are equivalent.

Comment: @dratenik this doesn't take into account the transformations/simplifications you can do in non-pathological cases. Even enormous expressions can be solved quite easily with modern sat solvers; not everything reduces to textbook 3SAT.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if a pair of expressions can be made equivalent, or that they are necessarily equivalent regardless of what the other inputs are? Note that these two are different in the SAT context. (For instance `A` and `B` can be made equivalent in a model, but they aren't necessarily equivalent in all models; assuming `A` and `B` are booleans by picking suitable values.)

Comment: @alias the expressions will be constraints over some constants, in my specific case some arrays of String -> String. So I would be trying to find whether there are two expressions that are equivalent for all possible values of those constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything performance related, the answer is "it depends." Before delving into options, though, note that z3 supports `Distinct`, which can check whether any number of expressions are all different: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a9eae89dd394c71948e36b5b01a7f3cd0

Though of course, you've a more complicated query here. I think the following two algorithms are your options:

### Explicit pairwise checks

Depending on your constraints, the simplest thing to do might be to call the solver multiple times, as you alluded to. To start with, use `Distinct` and make a call to see if its negation is satisfiable. (i.e., check if some of these expressions can be made equal.) If the answer comes `unsat`, you know you can't make any equal. Otherwise, go with your loop as before till you hit the pair that can be made equal to each other.

### Doing multiple checks together

You can also solve your problem using a modified algorithm, though with more complicated constraints, and hopefully faster.

To do so, create `Nx(N-1)/2` booleans, one for each pair, which is equal to that pair not being equivalent. To illustrate, let's say you have the expressions `A`, `B`, and `C`. Create:

- `X0 = A != B`
- `X1 = A != C`
- `X2 = B != C`

Now loop:

- Ask if `X0 || X1 || X2` is satisfiable.
- If the solver comes back `unsat`, then all of `A`, `B`, and `C` are equivalent. You're done.
- If the solver comes back `sat`, then at least one of the disjuncts `X0`, `X1` or `X2` is true. Use the model the solver gives you to determine which ones are false, and continue with those until you get `unsat`.

Here's a simple concrete example. Let's say the expressions are `{1, 1, 2}`:

- Ask if `1 != 1 || 1 != 2 || 1 != 2` is sat.
- It'll be sat. In the model, you'll have at least one of these disjuncts true, and it won't be the first one! In this case the last two. Drop them from your list, leaving you with `1 != 1`.
- Ask again if `1 != 1` is satisfiable. The answer will be `unsat` and you're done.

In the worst case you'll make `Nx(N-1)/2` calls to the solver, if it happens that none of them can be made equivalent with you eliminating one at a time. This is where the first call to `Not (Distinct(A, B, C, ...))` is important; i.e., you will start knowing that some pair is equivalent; hopefully iterating faster.

### Summary

My initial hunch is that the second algorithm above will be more performant; though it really depends on what your expressions really look like. I suggest some experimentation to find out what works the best in your particular case.

### A Python solution

Here's the algorithm coded:

```py
from z3 import *

exprs = [IntVal(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 10, 10, 1]]

s = Solver()

bools = []
for i in range(len(exprs) - 1):
  for j in range(i+1, len(exprs)):
    b = Bool(f'eq_{i}_{j}')
    bools.append(b)
    s.add(b == (exprs[i] != exprs[j]))

# First check if they're all distinct
s.push()
s.add(Not(Distinct(*exprs)))
if(s.check()== unsat):
    quit("They're all distinct")
s.pop()

while True:
    # Be defensive, bools should not ever become empty here.
    if not bools:
        quit("This shouldn't have happened! Something is wrong.")

    if s.check(Or(*bools)) == unsat:
        print("Equivalent expressions:")
        for b in bools:
          print(f'   {b}')
        quit('Done')
    else:
        # Use the model to keep bools that are false:
        m = s.model()
        bools = [b for b in bools if not(m.evaluate(b, model_completion=True))]
```

This prints:

```
Equivalent expressions:
   eq_0_8
   eq_1_5
   eq_2_4
   eq_6_7
Done
```

which looks correct to me! Note that this should work correctly even if you have 3 (or more) items that are equivalent; of course you'll see the output one-pair at a time. So, some post-processing might be needed to clean that up, depending on the needs of the upstream algorithm.

Note that I only tested this for a few test values; there might be corner case gotchas. Please do a more thorough test and report if there're any bugs!